Creating KQL query to get Azure VMs not patched since 30days
Im trying to create a KQL query to get Azure VMs not patched since 30days feature but it seems something in the query is wrong, but i've in pain figuring out what.
Here is the query using the let feature :
let Table01 = patchassessmentresources
| parse ["id"] with * "virtualMachines/" VmName "/patchAssessmentResults/" *
| extend publishedDateTime = todatetime(properties.publishedDateTime)
| extend patchName = properties.patchName
| extend kbId = properties.kbId
| extend patchId = properties.patchId
| extend TimeGenerated = todatetime(properties.lastModifiedDateTime)
| where TimeGenerated > ago(31d)
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches"
| extend classification = iff(properties.classifications[0] =~ "UpdateRollUp", "UpdateRollup", iff(isempty(properties.classifications[0]), "Unsupported", properties.classifications[0]))
| where classification contains "critical" or classification contains "security" or classification contains "Other"
| summarize FirstTimeSeen = arg_min(TimeGenerated, *) by VmName, subscriptionId;
let Table02 = patchassessmentresources
| parse ["id"] with * "virtualMachines/" VmName "/patchAssessmentResults/" *
| extend publishedDateTime = todatetime(properties.publishedDateTime)
| extend patchName = properties.patchName
| extend kbId = properties.kbId
| extend patchId = properties.patchId
| extend TimeGenerated = todatetime(properties.lastModifiedDateTime)
| where TimeGenerated > ago(31d)
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches"
| extend classification = iff(properties.classifications[0] =~ "UpdateRollUp", "UpdateRollup", iff(isempty(properties.classifications[0]),  "Unsupported", properties.classifications[0]))
| where classification contains "critical" or classification contains "security" or classification contains "Other" 
| summarize LastTimeSeen = arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by VmName, subscriptionId;
Table01
| join kind=inner Table02 on $left.['id'] == $right.['id']

Error :
Details:
Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the Azure Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying. (Code:InvalidQuery)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)
ParserFailure (Code:ParserFailure)

Errors are weird from my point of view :
image
I copied the approach from one of my previous query witch is weirdly working fine.
I hope someone could have a look on it and help :)
I've tried using the simple join feature which is working but 'tags' appears empty but should contains Azure VMs tags :
patchassessmentresources
| parse ["id"] with * "virtualMachines/" VmName "/patchAssessmentResults/" *
| extend publishedDateTime = todatetime(properties.publishedDateTime)
| extend patchName = properties.patchName
| extend kbId = properties.kbId
| extend patchId = properties.patchId
| extend TimeGenerated = todatetime(properties.lastModifiedDateTime)
| where TimeGenerated > ago(31d)
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches"
| extend classification = iff(properties.classifications[0] =~ "UpdateRollUp", "UpdateRollup", iff(isempty(properties.classifications[0]), "Unsupported", properties.classifications[0]))
| where classification contains "critical" or classification contains "security" or classification contains "Other" 
| summarize FirstTimeSeen =  arg_min(TimeGenerated, *) by VmName, subscriptionId
| join kind=leftouter (
    patchassessmentresources
    | parse ["id"] with * "virtualMachines/" VmName "/patchAssessmentResults/" *
    | extend publishedDateTime = todatetime(properties.publishedDateTime)
    | extend patchName = properties.patchName
    | extend kbId = properties.kbId
    | extend patchId = properties.patchId
    | extend TimeGenerated = todatetime(properties.lastModifiedDateTime)
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(31d)
    | where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches"
    | extend classification = iff(properties.classifications[0] =~ "UpdateRollUp", "UpdateRollup", iff(isempty(properties.classifications[0]),  "Unsupported", properties.classifications[0]))
    | where classification contains "critical" or classification contains "security" or classification contains "Other" 
    | summarize LastTimeSeen =  arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by VmName, subscriptionId
    ) on ['id']
| join kind=leftouter (
    resources
    | where type =~ "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
    | extend OsType = properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType
    | extend vmName = name
    | project vmName, id, location, tags, OsType
    ) on ['id']
| extend DifferenceBetweenFirstandLast = datetime_diff("day", LastTimeSeen, FirstTimeSeen)
| project VmName, subscriptionId, resourceGroup, location, FirstTimeSeen, LastTimeSeen, DifferenceBetweenFirstandLast, id, patchName, patchId, classification, ['tags']

Here is the picture, it is really weird as query from both let are working well separatly :
error picture
It is working well in your demo env but not in my tenant in Azure Graph Explorer.

Can you add to your question how patchassessmentresources looks like e.g.: as a JSON. To build a demo, to check your query.

Hello @decius, i don't see the goal here as you can copy paste the queries directly to Azure Graph Explorer.

The goal is to have a minimal reproducable code sample with the same data to check your query. I dont have a Azure Graph Explorer instance with the same data in patchassessmentresources like you have.

What is the expected result of your last query? Tags can be empty because tags could be a list e.g. I´ve checked your first query - there are no syntactic errors at least. So it has to do with the data and how you parse it.

I´ve created a minimal reproducable sample where we can work with.
This query works for me:
let patchassessmentresources = datatable(id: string, type: string, subscriptionId: string, properties: dynamic)
[
    'id1', "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches", "A", dynamic({
        "publishedDateTime": "2024-06-01T10:30:00Z",
        "patchName": "Patch1",
        "kbId": "KB1",
        "patchId": "PatchID1",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-06-01T10:30:00Z",
        "classifications": ["critical"]
    }),
    'id2', "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches", "A", dynamic({
        "publishedDateTime": "2024-06-02T11:00:00Z",
        "patchName": "Patch2",
        "kbId": "KB2",
        "patchId": "PatchID2",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-06-02T11:00:00Z",
        "classifications": ["security"]
    }),
    'id3', "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches", "A", dynamic({
        "publishedDateTime": "2024-06-03T12:45:00Z",
        "patchName": "Patch3",
        "kbId": "KB3",
        "patchId": "PatchID3",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-06-03T12:45:00Z",
        "classifications": ["Other"]
    }),
    'id4', "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches", "A", dynamic({
        "publishedDateTime": "2024-06-04T14:15:00Z",
        "patchName": "Patch4",
        "kbId": "KB4",
        "patchId": "PatchID4",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-06-04T14:15:00Z",
        "classifications": ["Unsupported"]
    }),
    'id2', "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches", "A", dynamic({
        "publishedDateTime": "2024-06-05T16:30:00Z",
        "patchName": "Patch5",
        "kbId": "KB5",
        "patchId": "PatchID5",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-06-05T16:30:00Z",
        "classifications": ["critical"]
    })
];
let Table01 = patchassessmentresources
| parse id with * "virtualMachines/" VmName "/patchAssessmentResults/" *
| extend publishedDateTime = todatetime(properties.publishedDateTime)
| extend patchName = properties.patchName
| extend kbId = properties.kbId
| extend patchId = properties.patchId
| extend TimeGenerated = todatetime(properties.lastModifiedDateTime)
| where TimeGenerated > ago(31d)
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches"
| extend classification = iff(properties.classifications[0] =~ "UpdateRollUp", "UpdateRollup", iff(isempty(properties.classifications[0]), "Unsupported", properties.classifications[0]))
| where classification contains "critical" or classification contains "security" or classification contains "Other"
| summarize FirstTimeSeen = arg_min(TimeGenerated, *) by VmName, subscriptionId;
let Table02 = patchassessmentresources
| parse id with * "virtualMachines/" VmName "/patchAssessmentResults/" *
| extend publishedDateTime = todatetime(properties.publishedDateTime)
| extend patchName = properties.patchName
| extend kbId = properties.kbId
| extend patchId = properties.patchId
| extend TimeGenerated = todatetime(properties.lastModifiedDateTime)
| where TimeGenerated > ago(31d)
| where type == "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/patchassessmentresults/softwarepatches"
| extend classification = iff(properties.classifications[0] =~ "UpdateRollUp", "UpdateRollup", iff(isempty(properties.classifications[0]),  "Unsupported", properties.classifications[0]))
| where classification contains "critical" or classification contains "security" or classification contains "Other" 
| summarize LastTimeSeen = arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by VmName, subscriptionId;
Table01
| join kind=inner Table02 on id

See also the Demo here.
Result:

Can you reproduce the error in my sample?

I'm having the same error with your demo, tried to add a picture but seems impossible :(
Line 56 'let' is in error
Line 68 'Table01' is in error

Really? It does not show this result (the screenshot in my answer)? Thats weird. :)

Add a screen shot to your question with add picture. just paste it.

Ok thats weird. Something is wrong with your environment. Because my sample code does not depend on other ressources or anything else. Maybe try another browser or in-cognito mode.

But the query itself is correct. At least syntactical.

Try ctrl + A and then click run, to mark the whole query. If that is not working, I´m running out of ideas. :)

Yes the query is correct, just tried in incognito mode, same same :(

ctrl+A makes no difference :(

Im going to create a support request
